# Texture onto 3D car mesh

Tags: c#, 3d, textures

I have a 3D car mesh object. How can I reflect a 3D text onto the 3D mesh surface?

I'm using [Visual Studio 2008 C# Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.23_Express). The 3D car mesh object is ready for use in C# project.
That is, I must use it in my C# project, not in [Blender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29).

All the development processes that I need must be done in C# development environment.

Comment: Do you have a bit more information? Are you doing this using open gl, or Direct 3D?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a 3D modeling tool like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), [AC3D](http://www.inivis.com/) or similar. This will help you create the "model" and placing any textures on it. Then you will also need some kind of drawing engine so you also can load and draw the model in your app.

Comment: Are Blender and AC3D trustable ? Any virus, etc. ? I have no any information on them. Could you give me some useful info. Thanks.

Comment: Blender is trustable. Don't know about AC3D though.

Comment: @J.Jan I can't see why AC3D wouldn't be trustable?!? It is widely used http://www.inivis.com/where.html and been available since 1996 http://www.inivis.com/about.html

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear specifically what you're talking about here.

Did you mean Text, or Texture?

Simply texturing the model - If you're using blender to create the model, texture it, and export it in .x or another format and render it using an appropriate library.

Reflecting Text - Look into projective decals.

Or a bit more advanced

Reflection of the environment - To simulate reflective surfaces you're going to need to program a shader. Look into HLSL, GLSL, CG, or you can do the shader in ASM. - [Reflection Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_mapping)

EDIT: Added link to reflection mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If you need Direct 3D access at run-time, try using SlimDX.